# Understanding MongoDB Aggregate and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I'm trying to do a query in MongoDB to first group by id and then sort descending. I have a functional LINQ expression here:

```
var list = this.GetPackages().ToList();
      list = list.OrderByDescending(package => package.PackageVersion)
        .GroupBy(g => g.PackageId)
        .Select(packages => packages.First()).ToList();
      return list;
```

But I can't seem to come up with the equivalent MongoDB expression, nor can I even get the $project function to work:

```
db.packages.aggregate([
    {
        $sort : { packageVersion : -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: "$PackageId" }
    },
    {
        $project: { PackageVersion: 1, Title: 1 }
    }
])
```

My result is this:

```
{ "_id" : "e3afb1fe-dce7-476e-8372-cd8201abc131" }
{ "_id" : "e3722179-0903-4894-9a86-3a3ffd94de83" }
{ "_id" : "3e65e93a-4c2c-4a02-8b21-e5858a4058dd" }
```

Is the MongoDB query of the correct format, and is there an equivalent way to do this using the C# MongoDB driver?

Comment: are you missing the `[]`? or is it just a typo? and the properties are case sensitive.

Comment: Oops, I added the brackets but it didn't change anything. I'll add the result into the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the `$first` operator and [$$ROOT](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) variable to get the first document in the group.

`$$ROOT` is a system variable that:

> References the root document, i.e. the top-level document, currently
>   being processed in the aggregation pipeline stage.

Then project the first document.

```
db.packages.aggregate([
    {
        $sort : { packageVersion : -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: { "_id": "$PackageId","firstPackage":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}
    },
    {
        $project: { "firstPackage": 1, "_id": 0}
    }
])
```

Comment: I used this code:

db.packages.aggregate([
    {
        $sort : { PackageVersion : -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: "$PackageId","PackageVersion":{$first:"$PackageVersion"} }
    }
])

which gets me closer, but I still need to select all properties, preferably without naming them explicitly in a project statement. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you need to use access it using `$$ROOT`. But you will get the document bound to a key. Please See the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, that worked, thanks, but can you explain what using $$ROOT does?

Comment: Is there any way to do it without having the document bound to a key?

Comment: No. You need to do that in the client side or you need to get all the properties of the first document in the group stage.