# c# and mongodb: Aggregates with filter

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, aggregate

I am using latest version of mongodb with MongoDB driver for C#. I created a little example, which should explain my problem. My goal ist to make some conditional Count(), conditional First() or an Average() with with filter. None of it works.

What would be the best solution to this problem. Thanks for any hint

```
    class MealDocument
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public Type type { get; set; }
        public double calorie { get; set; }
        public enum Type { breakfast, launch, dinner }
    }

    class MealAnalysis
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int numberOfBreakfast { get; set; }
        public DateTime firstLaunch { get; set; }
        public double averageDinnerCalorie { get; set; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var collection = Database.GetCollection<MealDocument>("meal_test");

        collection.InsertMany(new MealDocument[] {
            new MealDocument { name = "Thomas", type = MealDocument.Type.breakfast, calorie = 100, time = new DateTime(2017,8,1) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Thomas", type = MealDocument.Type.breakfast, calorie = 100, time = new DateTime(2017,8,2) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Thomas", type = MealDocument.Type.launch, calorie = 800, time = new DateTime(2017,8,3) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Thomas", type = MealDocument.Type.dinner, calorie = 2000, time = new DateTime(2017,8,4) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Peter", type = MealDocument.Type.breakfast, calorie = 100, time = new DateTime(2017,8,5) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Peter", type = MealDocument.Type.launch, calorie = 500, time = new DateTime(2017,8,6) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Peter", type = MealDocument.Type.dinner, calorie = 800, time = new DateTime(2017,8,7) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Paul", type = MealDocument.Type.breakfast, calorie = 200, time = new DateTime(2017,8,8) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Paul", type = MealDocument.Type.launch, calorie = 600, time = new DateTime(2017,8,9) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Paul", type = MealDocument.Type.launch, calorie = 700, time = new DateTime(2017,8,10) },
            new MealDocument { name = "Paul", type = MealDocument.Type.dinner, calorie = 1200, time = new DateTime(2017,8,11) }
        });

        var analysis = collection.Aggregate()
            .Group(
                doc => doc.name,
                group => new MealAnalysis
                {
                    name = group.Key,

                    // !!!! The condition in the Count() gets ignored
                    numberOfBreakfast = group.Count(m => m.type == MealDocument.Type.breakfast),

                    // !!!! Exception --> Not supported
                    averageDinnerCalorie = group.Where(m => m.type == MealDocument.Type.dinner).Average(m => m.calorie),

                    // !!!! Exception --> Not supported
                    firstLaunch = group.First(m => m.type == MealDocument.Type.launch).time
                }
            );

        var query = analysis.ToString();

        var result = analysis.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I will help you on my **lunch** break =). You are missing project part. Maybe this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315852/mongodb-driver-builders-how-to-group-and-get-average. I will get back to you in couple hours.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours and I can't get driver to work as you need it to. Although I didn't come up with correct solution this is closest I got. I am not a big fan of this solution because it calculates a lot you don't need but it might work good enough if Db is not that large and until you find solution to problem.

```
var groupRes = collection.Aggregate()
                .Group
                    (
                        x => new { x.name, x.type },
                        g => new
                        {
                            key = g.Key,
                            count = g.Count(),
                            averageCalorie = g.Average(y => y.calorie),
                            first = g.First().time
                        }
                    )
                .ToList();
            var paulStat = new MealAnalysis()
            {
                name = "Paul",
                averageDinnerCalorie = groupRes.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.key.name == "Paul" && x.key.type == Type.dinner)).averageCalorie,
                numberOfBreakfast = groupRes.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.key.name == "Paul" && x.key.type == Type.breakfast)).count,
                firstLaunch = groupRes.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.key.name == "Paul" && x.key.type == Type.launch)).first
            };
```

as you can see I calculate stuff you need for each enum and then construct for each person his `MealAnalysis`. Maybe someone finds solution you need.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for spending so much time. If I find out more, I will report

Comment: No problem, please do. I am very interested in what we are missing here.