# How to calculate the average of a single property in C# Mongodb strongly typed driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the official C# MongoDb strongly typed driver version 2.7.0 to interact with MongoDB.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Book {

    public ObjectId Id {get; set;}

    public string AuthorId {get; set;}

    public int PublishYear {get; set;}

    public double Price {get; set;}

}
```

How to get the average of the books prices (as a double) that belong to a specific author using the author id.

**Edit:-**

This is what I tried so far

```
var client = new MongoClient(ConnectionString);

var database = client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);

var books = database.GetCollection<Book>("Books");

var result = books.Aggregate().Match(b => b.AuthorId == authorId).Group<Book,double>(); //I stopped here at group
```

Comment: I could not apply the aggregate and group using the strongly typed driver. All the examples I found online explains that using raw queries.

Comment: So please post your effort here (code) and describe your *specific* and *isolated* issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing the following answer as an example

[MongoDB.Driver.Builders how to group and get average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315852/mongodb-driver-builders-how-to-group-and-get-average#31114707)

along with what you tried so far, try the following

```
var result = await books.Aggregate()
    .Match(b => b.AuthorId == authorId)
    .Group(b => b.AuthorId, g => 
        new {
            AuthorId = g.Key,
            AveragePrice = g.Average(p => p.Price)
        })
    .ToListAsync();
double average = result.Select(_ => _.AveragePrice).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this returns a List of averages?! It is supposed to be a single average

Comment: @Waxren how many records in the list? just select the first item in the list

Comment: It worked, the result list contains only one item put it can be simplified by 
result.FirstOrDefault().AveragePrice

Comment: @Waxren `FirstOrDefault` has the possibility to be `null`. which is why in this case I did the `Select` first. That way if the list is empty it will default to zero `(0)` and not throw an exception.